# Bought iPad from eBay locked to iCloud

Tags: ios, ipad

I've a just bought a iPad from eBay. The iPad came today and I found it to be locked to somebody else's iCloud account. Is there any way I can sort this situation out or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have purchased a stolen iPad. [See this answer.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40251/120171)

Answer (score 1):

You may have purchased a stolen iPad.  [eBay](http://pages.ebay.com/securitycenter/lawEnforcementReporting.html) has policies regarding the purchase of stolen goods and what you can do to report it to the authorities.  You may also be able to get you money back, but that is beyond the scope of Ask Different answers.

Comment: Definitely return it. Plus, I believe that you are still covered under eBay's Buyer Protection even if returns are not accepted, so long as you didn't know beforehand that it was iCloud locked. If not, you're stuck with a Apple-branded brick, and a stolen one at that...